# infinite scroll in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am using extjs 4.1 infinite scroll where data comes from server dynamically.
But the issue is that it is not working properly. Some white space is shown after data and after some time loading symbol comes.

I guess the reason behind this is data is not fetched equals to page size defined in the store.
The records fetched from server is random but it wont cross page size.

Please suggest which configs i have to use to fix this issue.

```
pageSize: 200,
leadingBufferZone: 400,
buffered: true,
remoteGroup: true,
purgePageCount: 5,
```

Thanks,
Sachin